# What technology should we use to build a realtime voice call analysis?

Tags: telephony, ivr, zoom-sdk, ringcentral

We need to build a system that will place a phone call to one party, listen to the response (for now, it will be a "hold music" playing), and connect this existing call to another party under certain circumstances.

I'm not asking what software we should use to analyze the streaming audio.
I'm asking what existing service (RingCentral, Zoom, another...) will allow us to:

1. automatically place a call
2. receive an audio stream
3. connect this call to another recipient

Comment: That's not what StackOverflow is for.